# How to use cubic custom-made iso files as Ubuntu local repository?

Tags: iso, custom-distributions, localrepository, apt-offline

I tried creating a custom iso image of  Ubuntu 22.04.2 using cubic software (https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic) by adding a few more packages (eg: vlc, gcc, and git) so that I can install all the required packages on a PC  without an Internet connection. Everything was successful and I could see that all the packages are installed on a new PC.

But when I mount the iso file, I am unable to locate the Debian packages in the iso file. I  am planning to use the custom-made iso file as a local repository as described in https://linuxconfig.org/add-iso-image-to-apt-sourceslist, and install the new packages in existing Ubuntu machines.
Can somebody explain how the newly added packages are stored in cubic custom-made iso file? Please also let me know how can I use this custom-made iso file as a local repository and install it on offline machines.